# Defining a variable in a js file, from a php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a javascript file that needs a value from a variable in a php script in which the JS file is being called.

```
<?
$sid = session_id();
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

How can i get $sid into the js file for use?

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myFile = 'myfile.php?sid=' + "<?php echo session_id() ?>";        
    $('#stuff').fadeOut("fast").load(myFile).fadeIn("fast");
</script>
```

The order of inclusion somewhat depends on what is inside javascript.js. If you are using the declared 'myFile' variable inside, declare it first. If it's just a lib, e.g. jQuery, declare it afterwards.

Comment: Changed the order, the variable needs to be before the JS file.

Comment: How would i place that var in the script as such;
  $('#stuff').fadeOut("fast").load('myfile.php?sid=').fadeIn("fast");

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth do you pass SID explicity? It should be passed throught cookies by PHP. Any other variable could be passed through sessions.

```
$('#stuff').fadeOut("fast").load('myfile.php?sid=<?php echo session_id() ?>').fadeIn("fast");
```

Read more about client/server languages and differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$sid = session_id();
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sid = '<?= $sid ?>';
</script>
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now you can use the **sid** variable in javascript.js, or any other JS code you load *AFTER* this.